# How php and own frameworks works in background?

Tags: php, frameworks

i am new on web programming .i am  good on c# .net platform on desktop. i tried to understand php and php frameworks but i get confused a little . i understand that a php file can import classes which is in the file into another php file  with require_once function. but frameworks doesnt  import his own classes with require_once function . i think they do something different which i dont understand.Can someone explain to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most frameworks uses a technique called "Autoloading" to automatically resolve and include needed dependencies.

An "Autoloader" is simply a function that is called by PHP when an unknown class is being referenced. That "Autoloader" can either procedurally create the class or simply `include` it from an external file based on the file name.

The current (PHP 5.1.2 and higher) proper way of doing so is by using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register). Here is an example of an autoloader:

```
function autoload_example($className) {
  $normalizedName = strtolower($className);

  if(file_exists('includes/' . $normalizedName . '.inc')) {
    require_once('includes/' . $normalizedName . '.inc');
  } elseif(file_exists('includes/' . $normalizedName . '.inc')) {
    require_once('includes/' . $normalizedName . '.php');
  } else {
    die('Class ' . $className . ' not found');
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_example');

$myAwesomeObject = new Awesome();
```

In the example above, PHP will run the "Autoloader" `autoload_example` when it will hit the reference to the class `Awesome`.

The "Autoloader" will first try to look for a file `include/awesome.inc`. If it can find it, it will include it.

If not, it will look for a file called `include/awesome.php`. If it can find it, it will include it.

If not, it will `die()` stating that it could not find my `Awesome` class.